# Xcode 12.5 - Packages cannot get information from info.plist

Tags: swift, facebook-login, xcode12

I recently updated my Xcode to version 12.5 and for some reason all of a sudden none of my packages were building correctly and producing errors.  To fix this I removed the packages and added them back, which solved the build errors.

However now when I try to log into Facebook on my application using this package [FacebookLogin](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) I am presented with the error *"App ID not found. Add a string value with your app ID for the key FacebookAppID to the Info.plist or call [FBSDKSettings setAppID:].'*

I have tried to manually configure this but still run into issues with the URL Scheme.

Has anyone encountered any similar issues as me and knows a way to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  I downloaded Xcode 12.4 again and used a previous commit and was able to get my code working.  It seems that are some errors on how Xcode 12.5 uses previous packages.  For reference I am using Firebase (7.9.1) and Facebook (8.2.0)

Comment: having the exact same issue... did you find a solution already?

Comment: Sorry @WernerHuber only just see this message now, have you found a solution since your comment?  I was only able to fix this by installing Xcode 12.4 and reverting to a previous commit.